# Promoting branches from Decision Center test to production environments

Tags: ibm-odm

Using ODM 8.10.5 in "cloud private" mode (OpenShift). We have three environments: review, test, and prod. Each has a distinct Decision Center and Rule Execution Server. We develop our ruleapps in the review DC using Rule Designer and sometimes just make changes in DC itself. We deploy from review DC to review RES, that all works. Fairly simple rulesets; we have almost 100 rules, but they're not fancy.

The problem is that we need to then promote these branches from review to test, and ultimately, test to prod. We'll be using the Decision Governance Framework, but our team is just starting our journey with that aspect.

How do we promote from review to test? We've tried exporting from DC and importing to the test DC, but that seems fraught with peril, and produces test branches that don't work, have missing bits like ruleflows.

Comment: Not really a solution, but in case someone else finds this: What we ended up doing was switching to just one Decision Center and have it deploy to all three Rule Execution Server environments. It's working well.